# Probability of point being inside triangle formed by 3 other points on boundary of square.

Tags: probability, geometry

I was trying this [problem](https://brilliant.org/practice/geometric-probability-level-4-5-challenges/?p=5) which I'll restate here:

"Three points are chosen uniformly at random from the boundary of a square and a fourth point is chosen uniformly at random from the interior. The probability that the 4th point lies in the triangle formed by the other 3 points can be expressed as $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are coprime positive integers. What is the value of $a+b$?"

I thought I solved this correctly, but my casework probabilities don't agree with the community solutions.

Essentially, this problem is asking for the average area of a triangle formed by 3 points on the boundary of a square. To calculate this, I broke it up into cases. Consider the events:

- $E_1$: All points on different sides.
- $E_2$: 2 points on same side, 1 point on adjacent side
- $E_3$: 2 points on same side, 1 point on opposite side
- $E_4$: 3 points on same side of square

Then,

$$\mathbb{E}[\text{Area}]= \sum_i \mathbb{E}[\text{Area}|E_i]P(E_i)$$

After some lengthy calculations I get $\mathbb{E}[\text{Area}|E_i]=\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{6},0$ for $i=1,2,3,4$ respectively, which agree with the solutions.

However, I got $P(E_1)=P(E_3)=P(E_4)=\frac{1}{5}$ and $P(E_2)=\frac{2}{5}$ which doesn't agree with the solutions. I arrived at this by counting the total number of arrangements of points as ${3+(4-1) \choose 3}=20$ by [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). Then I simply counted that there are 4 ways to get $E_1,E_3,E_4$, and 8 ways to get $E_2$. I confirmed this by exhaustively drawing out all 20 possibilities.

However, the solutions give $P(E_1)=\frac{3}{8}$, $P(E_2)=\frac{3}{8}$, $P(E_3)=\frac{3}{16}$, and $P(E_4)=\frac{1}{16}$. As part of this it is stated that there are $4^3$ total arrangements of points. But doesn't this assume that the points are distinguishable? I thought the point of using stars and bars was for arranging indistinguishable items, and points surely seem to count as indistinguishable.

Comment: As a general matter, it's hard to use Stars and Bars to compute probabilities, as the configurations counted by that method are not equally probable.

Comment: [Similar](https://www.3blue1brown.com/lessons/hardest-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking random points to form a polygon does not make the points indistinguishable. Suppose we pick four points on the square sides instead – depending on how we join them, the polygon may or may not be crossed, with correspondingly differing area.

Indeed, there can be no *algebraic* formula (not involving absolute values or the like) to give the absolute area of a triangle or other polygon from vertex coordinates alone.